# Rails Action Cable not transmitting a broadcast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a section in my app where a webpage just reloaded does NOT respond to an Action Cable broadcast, but after performing some tasks on it, it DOES respond to the same broadcast.

```
# When it works
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to Control:ExclusiveControl:a2714u146gf5: {:user=>"lKLZ0sea1512", ...}
ControlChannel transmitting {"user"=>"lKLZ0sea1512", ...} (via streamed from Control:ExclusiveControl:a2714u146gf5)

# When it doesn't work
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to Control:ExclusiveControl:a2714u146gf5: {:user=>"lKLZ0sea1512", ...}
```

I don't know why the ControlChannel isn't transmitting the broadcast. What should I look at to check this?